# Except() on EntityCollection vs List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, out-of-memory

Using EntityFramework 4. I have an `EntityCollection<SomeEntity> currentEntities` with ~500k entities and a `List<SomeEntity> importedEntities` also with ~500k records. I want to have the list of all records occuring in `currentEntities` which don't exist in `importedEntities`.

Calling `currentEntities.Select(x => x.ID).Except(importedEntities.Select(x => x.ID))` to get unique IDs of occurring records causes a `System.OutOfMemoryException` because it apparently loads all of the entities into the memory.

Calling `currentEntities.Where(x => !importedEntities.Any(y => y.ID == x.ID))` fails with `NotSupportedException` ("Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context").

`currentEntities` is on the SQL Server 2008 R2 database, while `importedEntities` are in memory.

Is this even possible in L2E ?

Comment: @Downvoter: care to explain why the down-vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing an `except` on two "large" lists of integers in memory is not a point. If I do `Enumerable.Range(0, 500000).Except(Enumerable.Range(500, 500000)).Count()` it returns 500 before I can say OutOfMemoryException. So I think reducing your problem to an `except` of integers should work for you:

```
var newIds = importedEntities.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray()
             .Except(currentEntities.Select(x => x.ID).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Thus, only integers will be loaded into memory, no entity objects.

Now you can do:

```
importedEntities.Where(x => newIds.Contains(x.ID))
```

provided that `newIds` is not too long. What is too long? The linq statement produces an `IN` clause, which can easily contain a couple of thousands of items, but if it is longer than, say, 10,000 you probably should process the IDs in chunks.

By the way (1). I'm assuming here that both lists are in different contexts, maybe even different databases. However, if they are in the same context, you might have success with:

```
importedEntities.Where(x => !currentEntities.Select(y => y.ID)
                           .Any(id => id == x.ID))
```

This produces a `NOT EXISTS` sql query. You may still run into an `OutOfMemoryException` though if there are "many" new items. If so, you could use a paging mechanism (`Skip` - `Take`) to process the new items in chunks.

By the way (2), I swapped currentEntities and importedEntities, because I assume you are interested in the new imported items, please undo that if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

The following is for when importedEntities is an in-memory collection, not a collection in the database.

```
var importedEntityIds = importedEntities
    .Select(x => x.ID).ToList(); // Convert to a list of some value type.
var result = currentEntities
    .Where(x => !importedEntityIds.Contains(x.ID))
    .ToList();
```

The following is for when importedEntities is a collection in the database.

```
var importedEntityIds = importedEntities
    .Select(x => x.ID); // This will be translated in SQL to a NOT IN (...)
var result = currentEntities
    .Where(x => !importedEntityIds.Contains(x.ID))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Did you maybe mean `var result = currentEntities.Select(x => x.ID).Where(x => !importedEntityIds.Contains(x.ID))` ?

Comment: Nope, that won't compile. First you select x.ID, then you try where !contains(x.ID), that is incorrect, the second x doesn't contain an ID property.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to figure out what new entries you need to add to some system or something.  This is not an uncommon occurrence.  Because your dataset is so big, either both cant exist in memory at the same time OR the various LINQ extension methods create copies of the collections in memory which busts through the memory max because you now have 3 or 4 copies of the lists in memory.

You might be able to use the fact that the results will be in an IEnumerable which will only load chunks of records as it iterates over the results from sql server.

Try this

```
foreach (var current in currentEntities)
{
    if (importedEntities.Contains(current))
    {
        importedEntities.Remove(current);
    }
}
```

The code assumes that the Equals and GetHashCode methods are overriden to compare the objects by the properties and not the default ones from object base class which just compares pointers or some low level stuff.

note: if you were to do the following

```
foreach (var current in currentEntities.ToList())
{
    if (importedEntities.Contains(current))
    {
        importedEntities.Remove(current);
    }
}
```

then you will get the System.OutOfMemoryException because now the whole database table is in memory not just the row you are trying to compare.  So DONT do the ToList or something like that.

Answer (score -1):

Select all ids from the imported entities:

`var importedids = importedEntities.Select(entity => entity.ID).ToList();`

Create a HashSet:

`var importedidshashset = new HashSet<int>(importedids);`

Filter currentEntities:

`currentEntities.Where(entity => !importedidshashset.Contains(entity.ID)).ToList().`

Comment: Why would this method be better than Maarten's ? It looks the same to me, except you additionally used a HashSet.

Comment: I had not seen Maartens answer when started typing my one. HashSet is crucial here (~500K records).

Comment: @Rawling: I am not talking about memory! I am talking about the time and O(n) instead of O(n^2)!

Comment: But the question specifically shows that the collections are too big to pull into memory. O(n) time is no good if you've not got the space to do it in.

Comment: @Rawling: Don't worry, I understood the question. I just wanted to draw his attention to the time complexity. I think it is really important if you have 2 collections 500K each.